# java parse html + css and convert the output to different lang

Tags: java, html-parsing, converters

i need to understand html + css files and convert it to somthing like rtf layot in java 
now i understand i need somekind of html parser but what i need to do from there ?
how can i implement html-css convertor ? is there somekind of patern or method 
for such jobs?

Comment: What do you mean by the html-css converter? For most cases, you are better off using an editor that supports both file types for conversion.

Comment: I don't think he/she means converting from html to css, but rather converting css-styled html to rtf. At least that's how I read it.

Comment: Is this any different than rendering the HTML+CSS?

Comment: its html css styled files converting to rtf kind of format

Comment: If possible, use the Google translator's web-page translation feature if you don't need 100% correct translation. Otherwise go for the other methods suggested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. At first use JTidy to convert HTML
   to valid XHTML
2. Apply an XSLT to
   convert to RTF
   using an
   XML library like Saxon or Xerces

Note: although I didn't
    find an xsl file for that conversion directly I'm
    sure there is one anywhere

Comment: An XSLT won't take account of the HTML document's CSS styling. (Or will it? I may be wrong.)

Comment: @Andrew Duffy: Well if it does not, it's a bad xslt. Although there my be a problem with external css, you can download that and insert it inline into the document to transform.

Comment: @Andrew Duffy: Of course you are right, it won't, cause the css is no xml... Stupid me... I'll go get some rest ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out HTMLEditorKit. It provides some support for CSS rendering. There is also an RTFEditorKit for writing, although it is not entirely reliable (last I checked, several years ago).

Is there a reason you need to use Java instead of just loading the HTML in Word (or some other editor) and saving it as RTF?  Also check [this W3C link](http://www.w3.org/Tools/html2things.html).

Comment: its have to be batch convector
something that needs to process allots of files

Comment: The link points to a number of headless transformers -- you may want to check those out.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [The Flying Saucer Project](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) that let you render XHTML to PDF. Maybe that could be used instead of RTF or the resulting PDF could be converted to RTF?